# Find data that internet is sending out in python

Tags: python, networking

I would like to find a simple way to find the specific data that my internet is sending out, and save it in a .txt file.

I would like it coded in python.

For example, if i visited https://beesbeesbees.com i would find something like `{address=https://beesbeesbees.com}{ip=123.123.1.231}` and more.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your internet is not sending data. if you wanted to track information about the requests that are made within your browser sessions you would obviously use a browser extension. Python is not capable of doing what you want

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated project, and can require a deep understanding of networking. While your data collection and organization aspect of this project can be written in Python, you're going to want to use other pre-existing tools to do the network capturing.

IMO, your best bet is to try [port-mirroring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) to a computer/VM/device that is running an application that listens on a port and processes some of that incoming data for you, like [Zeek](https://zeek.org/) (formerly Bro). YMMV.

Comment: im using wireshark now

Comment: and i have no idea how to use it

Comment: @BOI This video seems to explain the basics pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvuiI1Leg6w